Android actionBar navigation icon not showing desired color

I have created a vector asset drawable with a given colour, but while setting it in actionBar navigation icon , it is showing dark not the desired colour


activity actionBar screenshot
actionBar xml
app theme xml

i want a solution for getting a desired colour icon over toolbar
